# Is Transaction fees refund when deploy smart contract fail

Tags: blockchain, ether, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

[image]

I deployed a smart contract using hardhat to Ethereum mainnet, so the transaction fail, and my question is Transaction fee will be refunded to my wallet or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't get refund the gas fee because it paid to miner for more information about gas fees you can read [this.](https://media.consensys.net/ethereum-gas-fuel-and-fees-3333e17fe1dc)